# YouTube ajax, .replace() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replace, jsonp

I Am using the jquery below  and witht he addition of .replace(",", " ") to the var video_tags=data.tags doesn't return a value. how can i replace the commas with spaces.

### http://jsfiddle.net/hJGe4/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search_input").focus();
    $(".search_input").keyup(function () {
        $("#video").html('');
        var search_input = $(this).val();
        var keyword = encodeURIComponent(search_input);
        var yt_url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=' + keyword + '&format=5&max-results=6&v=2&alt=jsonc';
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : yt_url,
            dataType : "jsonp",
            success : function (response) {
                if (response.data.items) {
                    $.each(response.data.items, function (i, data) {
                        var video_title = data.title;
                        var video_tags = data.tags.replace(",", " ");
                        var final = video_title + '<br/>' + video_tags + '<br/><br/><br/>';
                        $("#video").append(final);
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#video").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var video_tags=data.tags.replace(",", " ");`

should be

`var video_tags=data.tags.join(" ");`

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hJGe4/5/)***